# Add text directly next to PHP variable?

Tags: php

I have a variable inside an inline style -

```
style='color:$custom_color;font-size:$custom_icon_size;'
```

And am trying to add the letters px directly after the $custom_icon_size. This obviously does not work? Any ideas what is the correct method?

thanks

Comment: Variables can't be parsed using single quotes, unless concatenated.

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to add "px".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `{}` around your PHP vaariable

`style='color:$custom_color;font-size:${custom_icon_size}px;'`

Comment: Thanks Brad. So simple.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're echoing it, you have two options:

```
echo "style='color:$custom_color;font-size:{$custom_icon_size}px;'";

echo "style='color:" . $custom_color . ";font-size:" . $custom_icon_size . "px;'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$style = 'color:'.$custom_color.'; font-size: '.$custom_icon_size.'px';
echo 'style="'.$style.'"';
```